# Laravel 5.4 Uploading more than one images and saving file name into database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4, save-image

i have a problem regarding inserting the filenames of the uploaded images in my database. My image upload was success but, in saving the filenames of the images in my database where i got a problem. When i execute my code, only one image filename was successfully save in my database.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.pictures') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input required type="file" id="images" name="images[]" multiple />
</form>
```

controller:

```
$input=$request->all();
$images=array();
if($files=$request->file('images')){
  foreach($files as $file){
    $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('image_files',$name);
    $images[]=$name;
  }
}
DB::table('product_images')->insert(array(
  'product_image'=>  implode("|",$images),
   'product_id'=>$product_id
));
```

i've only copied the code from browsing the internet. Do i need to loop the insert table? because when i tried this code, i selected 3 images and the three images are successfully uploaded but the filename of the first image was the only one that is being save in my database, i want the 3 image filenames to be inserted in database.

Comment: *$images[]=$name;* That's why only the first image is only saved. Try to count how many images has been uploaded and increment in. E.G : 
$i = 0;
 foreach($files as $file){
                $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move('image_files',$name);
                $images[$i++]=$name;
                }

Comment: you foreach array but put $name you need to make it `$file` as you foreach them

Comment: @AnarBayramov please answer my question below

Comment: @CamiloGo please answer below in formal way

Comment: @JcJohn i've answered below

Answer (score 0):

```
$images[]=$name;
```

That's why only the first image is only saved. 
Try to count how many images has been uploaded and increment in.

```
$i = 0; foreach($files as $file){ $name=$file->getClientOriginalName(); $file->move('image_files',$name); $images[$i++]=$name; }
```

Comment: `$images[] = $name` has the same effect as `array_push`. [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)